# Черный экран в cocos2dx

Tags: android, cocos2d

Сделал все как в этой статье [Cocos2D-X for iOS and Android: Getting Started](http://www.raywenderlich.com/11283/cocos2d-x-for-ios-and-android-getting-started).

После запуска `./build_native.sh`  все откомпилировалось. Зашел в eclipse, создал проект андроида из существующего, нажал Build Project. Запускаю приложение, на эмуляторе появляется только черный экран. Потратил несколько часов, но безрезультатно. Кто-нибудь знает, в чем дело?

Comment: а логи что говорят?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался в чем проблема. Оказывается новая версия кокоса(2.0) не поддерживает эмулятор андроида (какие-то заморочки с opengl_es), нужно отлаживать на самом устройстве.

Comment: Так как быть? Брать себе андроид устройство? Или сойдет и версия до 2?

Comment: Можно взять устройство. Но для того, чтобы проверить игру на различных диагоналях нужно все же эмулятор.